# What is intermittent administration?

Tags: terminology, blood-pressure

I have come across this study headline:

> Intermittent clonidine regimen abolishes tolerance to its antihypertensive effect: a spectral study

https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17414230/

I am not a native speaker of English and not sure I understand the headline.

What is intermittent administration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't understand a word the first place to go is a dictionary.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intermittent

> : coming and going at intervals : not continuous
>
> ```
> intermittent rain
> ```
>
> also : OCCASIONAL
>
> ```
> intermittent trips abroad
> ```

So intermittent administration means occasional administration, administration that isn't continuous. That could mean administration on some sort of schedule (daily, weekly, etc), or it could mean administration on an irregular basis. What you've quoted doesn't tell us if it's a regular schedule or not.